# What is the form of open sets of set of continuous functions?

Tags: general-topology

I'm starting learning general topology and I can't find out what the form of open sets of X with is.
$$X = C[a,b] = \{\space f : [a,b] \to \mathbb R \mid f \text{ is continuous }\}$$

Comment: In the real line there is  a simple description of all open sets in terms of open intervals but it is too much to expect a description of all open sets in more general spaces.

Comment: @Bungo or, possibly, without any metric at all.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by the euclidean metric on a space of functions?

Comment: There are many possible natural topologies on that set: the uniform topology, the topology of pointwise convergence, weak topologies,... Which one do you mean?

Answer (score 2):

The "whole point" of topology is that there's no way to define what an open set should be. In certain spaces, we have an intuitive idea of which sets we think should be open – for example, in $\mathbb{R}$, we define a set $X$ to be open when $\forall x \in X \exists \varepsilon > 0 \forall y \in \mathbb{R} (\lvert x - y \rvert < \varepsilon \implies y \in X)$. In other spaces, we might have some other definition of which sets should be open. The notion of a topological space exists because we noticed that in all of these cases, the collection of all "open sets" satisfies certain properties: it is always closed under arbitrary unions and finite intersections, etc.

A topological space is, of course, just a set paired with a collection of subsets that we call "open subsets". To drive home the point: there's nothing *intrinsically* "open" about the open sets in the topological space. The term "open set" is just shorthand for "an element of the topology", and most sets admit many different topologies! As such, it doesn't even make sense to ask what the open subsets of $C[a,b]$ are, because you described $C[a,b]$ as a set, and the concept of an open subset is only defined once you've equipped the set with a topology. Similarly, if you give $\mathbb{R}$ the discrete topology, every subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is open – there is nothing special about the sets we normally call "open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$" besides the fact that the corresponding topology on $\mathbb{R}$ shows up a lot.